# Starting a string at some column number

Tags: bash

I have two strings, which I want to print side by side.  But I want the second string to start from a certain column number.  What can I do?

Did play with the following, but `string2` prints backwards from position 21.

```
  n=21
  string1="Hello"
  string2="World!"
  p=$(( n - ${#string1} ))
  printf "%s%*s\n" "$string1" $p " $string2"
```

Result

```
         1         2  
123456789012345678901
Hello          World!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the first string to a fixed length.

```
n=20
printf "%-${n}.${n}s %s\n" "$string1" "$string2"
```

Comment: `printf '%-*.*s %s\n' "$n" "$n" "$string1" "$string2"` to not inject a shell variable into the `printf` format string.